# Export and import huge data using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 200,000 record in my database on localhost, I want to add all record on the server, using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Did you try to export it from local and importing it to the server?

Comment: yes, I wan't to export it from local and importing it to the server

Answer (score 0):

> Method for large import

there's a setting  `$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';` in config.inc.php set this to `$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'Upload';` and create a folder with name **Upload** in the directory phpmyadmin and copy the sql script into this folder... u'll start to see this file name in phpmyadmin import section

Comment: iI donit have this privilage , I'm using rackapace

Comment: I haven't used rackspace but I am sure rackspace guys will help with this importing issue, after all you have paid for their service and support.